# Red Black Tree (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, red-black-tree

I am trying to implement a simple red-black tree (in C) with an extra function that calculates the clock time throughout the period of inserting and searching in the tree.
I did use the debugger (gdb) and nada, can't find any solution.

```
// colori RBT
    enum colori{
        RED = 0,
        BLACK = 1
    };
    
    
    //nodo albero RBT
    typedef struct nodo_alberoRBT{
        int chiave;
        enum colori color;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT *padre;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT *figlio_sinistro;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT *figlio_destro;
    } nodo_alberoRBT;
    
    //struct nodo_alberoRBT t_nil;
    //nodo_alberoRBT* NIL = &t_nil;
    
    // albero RBT
    struct alberoRBT{
        int cardinalita;
        struct nodo_alberoBST *root;
    };
    
    // nodo NIL
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* NIL(){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* temp = (nodo_alberoRBT*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_alberoRBT));
        temp->color = BLACK;
        temp->padre = NULL;
        temp->figlio_sinistro = NULL;
        temp->figlio_destro = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    
    // nuovo nodo RBT
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* nuovoNodoRBT(int oggetto){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* temp = (nodo_alberoRBT*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_alberoRBT));
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        temp->chiave = oggetto;
        temp->color = RED;
        temp->padre = NULL;
        temp->figlio_sinistro = NULL;
        temp->figlio_destro = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* root(int oggetto){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* temp = (nodo_alberoRBT*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_alberoRBT));
        temp->chiave = oggetto;
        temp->color = BLACK;
        temp->padre = NULL;
        temp->figlio_sinistro = NULL;
        temp->figlio_destro = NULL;
        return temp;
    } 
    
    
    
    // ricerca del nodo RBT
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* searchRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root, int chiave){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        if((root == t_nil) || (root->chiave == chiave)){
            return root;
        }
    
        if(chiave <= root->chiave) {
            return searchRBT(root->figlio_sinistro, chiave);
        } else {
            return searchRBT(root->figlio_destro, chiave);
        }
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* LeftRotate(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root, struct nodo_alberoRBT* x){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* y = x->figlio_destro;
        x->figlio_destro = y->figlio_sinistro;
    
        if(y->figlio_sinistro != t_nil){
            y->figlio_sinistro->padre = x;
        }
    
        y->padre = x->padre;
    
        if(x->padre == t_nil){
            root = y;
        }
    
        if((x->padre != t_nil) && (x == x->padre->figlio_sinistro)){
            x->padre->figlio_sinistro = y;
        }
    
        if((x->padre != t_nil) && (x == x->padre->figlio_destro)){
            x->padre->figlio_destro = y;
        }
    
        y->figlio_sinistro = x;
        x->padre = y;
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* RightRotate(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root, struct nodo_alberoRBT* x){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* y = x->figlio_sinistro;
        x->figlio_sinistro = y->figlio_destro;
    
        if(y->figlio_destro != t_nil){
            y->figlio_destro->padre = x;
        }
    
        y->padre = x->padre;
    
        if(x->padre == t_nil){
            root = y;
        }
    
        if((x->padre != t_nil) && (x == x->padre->figlio_destro)){
            x->padre->figlio_destro = y;
        }
    
        if((x->padre != t_nil) && (x == x->padre->figlio_sinistro)){
            x->padre->figlio_sinistro = y;
        }
    
        y->figlio_destro = x;
        x->padre = y;
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* FixUpLeft(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root,struct nodo_alberoRBT* z){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* y = z->padre->padre->figlio_destro;
        if(y->color == RED){
            z->padre->color = BLACK;
            y->color = BLACK;
            z->padre->padre->color = RED;
            z = z->padre->padre;
        } else {
            if(z == z->padre->figlio_destro){
                z = z->padre;
                LeftRotate(root, z);
            }
            z->padre->color = BLACK;
            z->padre->padre->color = RED;
            RightRotate(root, z->padre->padre);
        }
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* FixUpRight(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root,struct nodo_alberoRBT* z){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        z->padre->padre->figlio_sinistro = t_nil;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* y = z->padre->padre->figlio_sinistro ;
        if(y->color == RED){
            z->padre->color = BLACK;
            y->color = BLACK;
            z->padre->padre->color = RED;
            z = z->padre->padre;
        } else {
            if(z == z->padre->figlio_sinistro){
                z = z->padre;
                RightRotate(root, z);            
            }
            z->padre->color = BLACK;
            z->padre->padre->color = RED;
            LeftRotate(root, z->padre->padre);
        }
    }
    
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* RBT_Insert_Fixup(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root,struct nodo_alberoRBT* z){
        while(z->padre->color == RED){
            if(z->padre == z->padre->padre->figlio_sinistro){
                FixUpLeft(root, z);
            } else {
                FixUpRight(root, z);
            }
        } 
        root->color = BLACK;
    }
    
    // inserimento RBT
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* insertRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT* root,struct nodo_alberoRBT* z){
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_nil = NIL();
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* y;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* x;
        y = t_nil;
        x = root;
        while(x != t_nil){
            y = x;
            if (x == NULL) { printf("Bummer\n"); exit(1); }
            if(z->chiave <= x->chiave){   
                x = x->figlio_sinistro;   
            } else {
                x = x->figlio_destro;
            }
        }
    
        z->padre = y;
    
        if(y == t_nil){
            root = z;
        }
    
        if((y != t_nil) && (z->chiave < y->chiave)){
            y->figlio_sinistro = z;
        }
    
        if((y != t_nil) && (z->chiave >= y->chiave)){
            y->figlio_destro = z;
        }
    
        z->figlio_sinistro = t_nil;
        z->figlio_destro = t_nil;
        z->color = RED;
        RBT_Insert_Fixup(root, z);
    }
    
    void RBTreeDeallocate(struct nodo_alberoRBT *root){
        if(root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        RBTreeDeallocate(root->figlio_sinistro);
        RBTreeDeallocate(root->figlio_destro);
        free(root);
    }
    
    float singolo_esperimentoRBT(int max_chiavi, int max_search, int max_delete, int max_istanze){
        double t_tot = 0;
        int istanza = 0;
        int chiave, ricerca, eliminazione;
        struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_root;
    
        for(istanza = 1 ; istanza <= max_istanze ; istanza++){
            srand(0);
            t_root = root(rand());
            //t_root = nuovoNodoRBT(rand());
            clock_t inizioTempo, fineTempo; //dichiaro queste due variabili di tipo clock_t (typedef)
            inizioTempo = clock();
            for(chiave = 1; chiave <= max_chiavi; chiave++){
                insertRBT(t_root,nuovoNodoRBT(rand()));
            } 
    
            /*for(ricerca = 1; ricerca <= max_search; ricerca++){
                searchRBT(t_root, rand());
            } */
    
            fineTempo = clock(); // termina il tempo
            double differenzialeTempo = (double) (fineTempo - inizioTempo);  //differenza tra tempo di fine e inizio
            t_tot = t_tot + differenzialeTempo; // sommo il tempo totale dell'esperimentoBST singolo
            RBTreeDeallocate(t_root); // deallocazione dell'albero RBT
        }
    
        return t_tot/max_chiavi;
    }
    
    void esperimentoRBT(int min_chiavi, int max_chiavi){
        int step = 10;
        int istanze_massime = 5;
        int percentuale_ricerca = 60;
        int chiavi = 0, seed = 0;
        double tempoBST = 0 , tempoRBT = 0;
        for(chiavi = min_chiavi; chiavi <= max_chiavi; chiavi = chiavi + step){
            double max_search = chiavi * percentuale_ricerca/100;
            double max_delete = chiavi - max_search;
            tempoBST = singolo_esperimentoBST(chiavi, max_search, max_delete, istanze_massime);
            tempoRBT = singolo_esperimentoRBT(chiavi, max_search, max_delete, istanze_massime);
            printf("Tempo BST: %f - Tempo RBT: %f - Chiavi: %d\n", tempoBST,tempoRBT, chiavi);
        }
    }
    
    int main(void){
        int min_chiavi = 10;
        int max_chiavi = 100;
    
        esperimentoRBT(min_chiavi, max_chiavi);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

For some reason, I do receive the segmentation fault message as soon as I launch it :( My hypothesis is that it happens whenever the program tries to enter in the function `Singolo_EsperimentoRBT`.

Comment: The mixture of `t_nil` and `NULL` does not bode well.

Comment: You should represent NIL nodes using a null pointer, not a pointer to an allocated block, especially because you call `NIL()` in several places to allocate a NIL node and then compare existing pointers with the pointer to the newly allocated NIL node. None of the existing pointers will compare equal to the newly allocated NIL nodes.

Comment: @Arkku· NULL in the IF of the insert function is a test for my code and is irrilevant because i add him after segmentation fault error.

Comment: Do you get a stack traceback with the segmentation error?   It'd be great to isolate the problem point.

Comment: @MarkLavin segmentation error is in the second loop of the while in "insert" function because the assignment between x and x.leftChild, assign NULL to x and after when z.key is compared with x.key which is null by segmentation error.

Comment: @FRANCESCOBARIONI Your `== t_nil` checks won't work, as explained by Ian above. If you want to use one node designated as `t_nil`, it needs to be a singleton, and you should not also use `NULL`. But on a quick glance I see no reason to not just use `NULL` here. Some kind of sentinel node can simplify some data structure implementations, but that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Arkku If I understand correctly you are recommending in this particular situation to replace all t_nils with NULL to simplify the implementation? With the aim of making it work.Thank you for your another answer!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Red-Black Tree delete related functions implementation - RBT Minimum - Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70303772/red-black-tree-delete-related-functions-implementation-rbt-minimum-segmentat)