# Red-Black Tree delete related functions implementation - RBT Minimum - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, red-black-tree

I am currently implementing an Red-Black Tree (RBT) function. So far the insertion and the search function are working as they should. However here comes the "annoying" part. I am trying to implement a function which performs the deletion. Everything works fine in the delete, delete Fix Up and in the transplant, but when it comes to the "Minimum" function, I do get a segmentation fault. Most probably I haven't written that function correctly, coudl you guys kindly help me out?

Here is the code related to this deletion part:

```
void rotateLeft( nodo_alberoRBT** T, nodo_alberoRBT* x)
{
    nodo_alberoRBT *y  = x->figlio_destro;    
    x->figlio_destro = y->figlio_sinistro;     
    if (y->figlio_sinistro != T_Nil)
        y->figlio_sinistro->padre = x;
    y->padre = x->padre;  
    if (x->padre == T_Nil)
        *T = y;
    else if (x == x->padre->figlio_sinistro)
        x->padre->figlio_sinistro = y;
    else
        x->padre->figlio_destro = y;
    y->figlio_sinistro   = x;            
    x->padre = y;
}

void rotateRight(nodo_alberoRBT** T, nodo_alberoRBT* y)
{
    nodo_alberoRBT *x  = y->figlio_sinistro;     
    y->figlio_sinistro  = x->figlio_destro;    
    if (x->figlio_destro != T_Nil)
        x->figlio_destro->padre = y;
    x->padre = y->padre;  
    if (y->padre == T_Nil)
        *T = x;
    else if (y == y->padre->figlio_destro)
        y->padre->figlio_destro = x;
    else
        y->padre->figlio_sinistro  = x;
    x->figlio_destro  = y;         
    y->padre = x;
}

void transplantRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT** root, struct nodo_alberoRBT* u, struct nodo_alberoRBT* v){
    if(u->padre == T_Nil){
        *root = v;
    } 
    else if(u == u->padre->figlio_sinistro){
        u->padre->figlio_sinistro = v;
    } else {
        u->padre->figlio_destro = v;
    }

    v->padre = u->padre;
}

void deleteFixupRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT** root, struct nodo_alberoRBT* x){
    while((x != root[0]) && (x->color == BLACK)){
        if(x == x->padre->figlio_sinistro){
            struct nodo_alberoRBT* w = x->padre->figlio_destro;

            if(w->color == RED){
                w->color = BLACK; // caso 1
                x->padre->color = RED; // caso 1
                rotateLeft(root, x->padre); // caso 1
                w = x->padre->figlio_destro; // caso 1
            }

            if((w->figlio_sinistro->color == BLACK) && (w->figlio_destro->color == BLACK)){
                w->color = RED; // caso 2
                x = x->padre; // caso 2
            }
            else if(w->figlio_destro->color == BLACK){
                w->figlio_sinistro->color = BLACK; // caso 3
                w->color = RED; // caso 3
                rotateRight(root, w); // caso 3
                w = x->padre->figlio_destro; // caso 3
            } else {
                w->color = x->padre->color; // caso 4
                x->padre->color = BLACK; // caso 4
                w->figlio_destro->color = BLACK; // caso 4
                rotateLeft(root, x->padre); // caso 4
                x = root[0]; // caso 4
            }
        } else {
            struct nodo_alberoRBT* w = x->padre->figlio_sinistro;

            if(w->color == RED){
                w->color = BLACK; // caso 1
                x->padre->color = RED; // caso 1
                rotateRight(root, x->padre); // caso 1
                w = x->padre->figlio_sinistro; // caso 1
            }

            if((w->figlio_destro->color == BLACK) && (w->figlio_sinistro->color == BLACK)){
                w->color = RED; // caso 2
                x = x->padre; // caso 2
            }
            else if(w->figlio_sinistro->color == BLACK){
                w->figlio_destro->color = BLACK; // caso 3
                w->color = RED; // caso 3
                rotateLeft(root, w); // caso 3
                w = x->padre->figlio_sinistro; // caso 3
            } else{

                w->color = x->padre->color; // caso 4
                x->padre->color = BLACK; // caso 4
                w->figlio_sinistro->color = BLACK; // caso 4
                rotateRight(root, x->padre); // caso 4
                x = root[0]; // caso 4
            }
        }
    }
    x->color = BLACK;
}

// nodo minimo
struct nodo_alberoRBT* nodo_minimoRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT* nodo){
    while(nodo->figlio_sinistro != T_Nil){
        nodo = nodo->figlio_sinistro;
    }

    return nodo;
}

struct nodo_alberoRBT* successoreRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT* nodo){
    if(nodo != T_Nil){
        return nodo_minimoRBT(nodo->figlio_destro);
    }

    struct nodo_alberoRBT* nodo2 = nodo->padre;
    while(nodo2 != T_Nil && nodo == nodo2->figlio_destro){
        nodo = nodo2;
        nodo2 = nodo2->padre;
    }

    return nodo2;
}

void deleteRBT(struct nodo_alberoRBT** root, struct nodo_alberoRBT* z){
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* y = z;
    char y_colore_originale;
    y_colore_originale = y->color;
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* x;

    if(z->figlio_sinistro == T_Nil){
        x = z->figlio_destro;
        transplantRBT(root, z, z->figlio_destro);
    } 
    else if(z->figlio_destro == T_Nil){
        x = z->figlio_sinistro;
        transplantRBT(root, z, z->figlio_sinistro);
    }
    else {
        y = nodo_minimoRBT(z->figlio_destro);
        y_colore_originale = y->color;
        x = y->figlio_destro;
        if(y->padre == z){
            x->padre = y;
        } else {
            transplantRBT(root, y, y->figlio_destro);
            y->figlio_destro = z->figlio_destro;
            y->figlio_destro->padre = y;
        }
        transplantRBT(root, z, y);
        y->figlio_sinistro = z->figlio_sinistro;
        y->figlio_sinistro->padre = y;
        y->color = z->color;
    }

    if(y_colore_originale == BLACK){
        deleteFixupRBT(root, x);
    }

    root[0]->color = BLACK;
}

float singolo_esperimentoRBT(int max_chiavi, int max_search, int max_delete, int max_istanze){
    double t_tot = 0;
    int istanza = 0;
    int chiave, ricerca, eliminazione;
    struct nodo_alberoRBT* t_root;

    for(istanza = 1 ; istanza <= max_istanze ; istanza++){

        t_root = T_Nil;
        clock_t inizioTempo, fineTempo; //dichiaro queste due variabili di tipo clock_t (typedef)
        inizioTempo = clock(); // inizia il tempo

        for(eliminazione = 1; eliminazione <= max_delete; eliminazione++){
            deleteRBT(&t_root, newNode(rand()));
        } 

        fineTempo = clock(); // termina il tempo
        double differenzialeTempo = (double) (fineTempo - inizioTempo);  //differenza tra tempo di fine e inizio
        t_tot = t_tot + differenzialeTempo; // sommo il tempo totale dell'esperimentoBST singolo

    }

    return t_tot/max_chiavi;
}

void esperimentoRBT(int min_chiavi, int max_chiavi){
    int step = 10000;
    int istanze_massime = 5;
    int percentuale_ricerca = 60;
    int chiavi = 0; 
    int seed = 164333; // seed
    double tempoBST = 0 , tempoRBT = 0;
    for(chiavi = min_chiavi; chiavi <= max_chiavi; chiavi = chiavi + step){
        double max_search = chiavi * percentuale_ricerca/100;
        double max_delete = chiavi - max_search;
        srand(seed);
        tempoBST = singolo_esperimentoBST(chiavi, max_search, max_delete, istanze_massime); // richiamo s.esperimento BST
        tempoRBT = singolo_esperimentoRBT(chiavi, max_search, max_delete, istanze_massime); // richiamo s.esperimento RBT
        printf("Tempo RBT: %f - Chiavi: %d\n",tempoRBT, chiavi);

        seed++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int min_chiavi = 10000;
    int max_chiavi = 100000;

    esperimentoRBT(min_chiavi, max_chiavi);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody will be able to read your code.  Can you also post a `main` with a test that fails ?

Comment: @alinsoar I have posted the main function.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are almost certainly wrong:

if((w->figlio_destro->color == BLACK) && (w->figlio_sinistro->color == BLACK))

because if you delete x as a node and it is a leaf node, w (its sibling) will exist, but w's children may not exist. That means w->figlio_destro may be NULL and w->figlio_sinistro may be NULL

You should have a function (maybe inline)

bool IsBlack(const nodo_alberoRBT* n) { return n == NULL || n->colour == BLACK)

and use that.

The same is true for the Insert case. The Uncle of the Parent node of the inserted node at the bottom, may not exist

Black Node: May not exist if leaf otherwise it does exist
Red Node: Always real